# How to delete an arrow created with ax.arrow()?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

For context, I have a curve where I would like to highlight the width of a plateau with an annotation + an arrow (this one was made in Paint.NET).

[image]

To update the text and arrow, every time an input parameter changes I do:

```
ax.texts = [] # Clear the previous annotations.
ax.text(x, y, plateau_width_str)
??? # What goes here to clear the arrow? 
ax.arrow(x, y, dx=plateau_width, dy=0)
```

For now I'm not using `gid`s here because I only have one text and one annotation at a time. What should be the third line? After calling `ax.arrow()` I tried exploring `ax.collections` and `ax.patches` but they are empty lists. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd just try to catch whatever `ax.arrow()` returns and delete it before issuing it again. But I have not tried it.

Comment: That works (`arrow.remove()` not `del arrow`) but it forces to store a reference which I don't like a lot. Looping through a container and checking for its elements's `gid` is much cleaner than keeping the refs of all the objects drawn.

Comment: I am not sure you can get a reference to that specific arrow object in other ways, though.

Comment: I can do it for scatters (`ax.collections`) and plots (`ax.lines`) easily usually, so arrows probably work the same way. I just don't know their container :( Their type `type(ax.arrow(...))` is `<class 'matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow'>` so it should be stored somewhere in `ax.patches`.

Comment: You can always look at `ax.get_children` to see all drawn elements. I would assume that it is a patch/polygon object.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. Hence `myarrow = ax.arrow(..); myarrow.remove()` is in general the prefered way to solve this. (The arrow is in `ax.artists`, you can remove it from that list, but it will require to identify it first, so any such solution will be much more complicated.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you, you are very helpful on many Matplotlib questions. I agree explicit is better, but I typically hide implementations details behind an abstract one-liner (say `remove_artist(ax, gid)` ) that loops through `ax.artists` and deletes the target identified by `gid == artist.get_gid()`. It's easier for me to use that in a main program, and it supports multiple objects thanks to `gid`s. Also, how do you know arrows are in `ax.artists`? It's not in the doc.

Comment: It's not in the docs, because it shoudn't matter where it is. The prefered way to get an artist is to have a reference to it, or else to use `ax.findobj()` with sufficient criteria.

Comment: I typically use this, which I find readable: https://i.imgur.com/iM3aqkH.png You think it's dirty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly create a method that removes the old and creates a new arrow, like `self.create_arrow(*args, **kwargs)`.

It might look like

```
def create_arrow(self, *args, **kwargs):
    gid = kwargs.get("gid")
    if gid in self.some_dic:
        self.some_dic[gid].remove()
    arrow = self.ax.arrow(*args, **kwargs)
    self.some_dic.update({kwargs.get("gid") : arrow})
```

Where you have a dictionary `self.some_dic` to store the references in.

Comment: Storing the reference in a dict works, as with saw with norok2, but my goal was to avoid storing anything in my main program since that's what axes do already. I'll stick to my abstract one-liner that loops through `ax.artists` and searches for a `gid`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the following:

`ax.get_children()` -> to get the list of all objects of axes after

`ax.get_children()[0].remove()` -> to remove the 0-element of axes list.

If you try `ax.get_children()` again you get a new list with the number of objects reduced, and the place **"0"** was substituted by the **[1] element of the previous list**. Then, every time you use `ax.get_children()[0].remove()` you will remove the sequence of elements, erasing each element that takes place which was removed before. Be careful!

Or you can try to choose the right element by setting the **ID_number** when you use `ax.get_children()[ID_number].remove()`.